# Creating Multiple Tables Using Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create and import multiple (4000) csv files into my postgres database using psycopg2. All the csv files have the same column names and types. I just can't figure out how to order this efficiently.

Python 3.5, Postgre - 9.5.12

Problems:

- .format is not working properly (not replacing '%s' with sec_name)
- Should I specify the columns I want to insert into or use copy_from
- Can I simplfy this process anymore

  ```
  import psycopg2
  import os

  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres")
  cur = conn.curser()

  # file_dir == directory containing all the .csv
  sec_files = os.listdir("file_dir")

  for files in sec_files:

      # Cuts off all whitespace and .csv
      sec_name = ''.join(files.split())[:-4]

      cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE '%s' (
          Date NOT NULL UNIQUE DATE PRIMARY KEY
          col2 FLOAT NOT NULL
          col3 FLOAT NOT NULL
          col4 FLOAT NOT NULL
          col5 FLOAT NOT NULL
          col6 FLOAT NOT NULL
          col7 INTEGER  NOT NULL )''').format(sec_name)
       print("Table created ",sec_name)

      with open(os.path.abspath(files),'r') as f:
          next(f)
          for row in reader:
               cur.copy_from(f,sec_name, sep=',')

      conn.commit()
      print('Data inserted into ', sec_name, ' completed')
  ```

Comment: don't use `format` you're prone to SQL injections, if you want to insert table names you'll need the `AsIs` module from `psycopg2.extensions`, also you're trying to make 4000 tables? something seems off....

Comment: I don't understand how to use psycopg2.extensions.AsIs. And yes 4000.

Comment: something is wrong in your design pattern if you're making 4000 tables, just saying...

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted your code, didn't change the way you insert data seeing as that would be a bit more refactor but given what you have shown this would be the proper way to perform the code you have presented.

```
import os
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

query = """
        CREATE TABLE %(table)s (
            Date NOT NULL UNIQUE DATE PRIMARY KEY
            col2 FLOAT NOT NULL
            col3 FLOAT NOT NULL
            col4 FLOAT NOT NULL
            col5 FLOAT NOT NULL
            col6 FLOAT NOT NULL
            col7 INTEGER  NOT NULL)
        """

sec_files = os.listdir('file_dir')
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgres user=postgres')

with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    for file in sec_files:
        name = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]
        cursor.execute(query, {'table': AsIs(name)})
        print('Table created', name)

        with open(os.path.abspath(file), 'r') as fin:
            next(f)
            cursor.copy_from(f, name, sep=',')
            print('Data inserted into ', name, ' complete')
```